# Counterexample for mean value theorem

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Using Lagrange's mean value theorem. We have
$$\frac{f(x_0+\Delta x)-f(x_0)}{\Delta x}=f'(x_0+\theta \Delta x)$$
Taking limits on both sides, we see that the limit of the derivative always equals to the value of the derivative at $x_0$. 
But here is a counter example:

$f(x)=x^2 \sin \frac 1 x$ , for $x\neq 0$ , And

$f(x)=0$ , for $x=0$

This function is continuous ,say, on the interval [-1,1]. Also, each point in it has a finite derivative. That is to say, it satisfies the condition of the mean value theorem.

But $f'(0)=0$, while $\lim_{x\to 0} f'(x)$ doesn't exist at all.

Can you explain this contradiction ?

**Actually this's an example in Фихтенгольц's(Fikhtengolz) Calculus book. But he didn't clarify it.**

Comment: What makes you think "taking limits on both sides" is valid, when the right-hand side isn't continuous? (Even if $\theta$ were continuous as a function of $\Delta x$, which the MVT does not promise you, $f'$ itself is not continuous).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MVT depends on the range of appropriate values of $f'$ being present on the interval $(0,h)$, which is not the same thing as the limit. If you graph $f'$ you'll see it is highly oscillatory but $f'((0,h))$ should basically give you the same interval for all $h$ small.

Let me put it another way: Can you explain to me how the MVT implies continuity of $f'$? This is what you are assuming.

---

Here's an explanation for why you cannot take the limit of each side to conclude that $f'(0)=\lim_{h \to 0} f'(h)$. Consider the sequential formulation of limits, that is $\lim_{h \to 0} g(h)=L$ if for all $h_n\to 0 $ we have $g(h_n) \to 0$.

Let $h_n \to 0$ be arbitrary. The MVT states that for each $n$, we have
$$\frac{f(h_n)-f(0)}{h_n}=f'(0+\theta(h_n)h_n).$$
Please note that $\theta(h_n)$ is in $(0,1)$ and depends on $h_n$.
Taking $n \to \infty$ gives
$$f'(0)=\lim_{n \to \infty} f'(\theta(h_n)h_n).$$
But, $\theta(h_n) h_n$ does not necessarily range through all sequences going to zero no matter how $h_n$ is picked. So we can't conclude that the RHS is $\lim_{h \to 0} f'(h)$.

Comment: By taking limits on both sides for the first formula, and take x0=0.

Comment: @zhimengfan: What makes you think "taking limits on both sides" is valid?

Comment: @Makholm. I think continuity is not a necessity for the existence of limit

Comment: @zhimengfan: But what makes you think the limit ought to exist at all? It doesn't. And you have not presented anything that gives you a right to expect it would.

Comment: Since the left side equals to the right side, for the first formula. then they must have the same limit(of course, also, limit must simultaneously exist or doesn't exist.) because they are definitely the same function of $\Delta x$

Comment: @zhimengfan See my edit.